How do I enumerate s3 buckets and objects?
I am able to get a PreSignedUrl if I know my object's key and my bucket name.  However I cannot enumerate either my buckets or the objects in my buckets:
const string keyName = "name";
const string accessKey = @"key";
const string secretKey = @"secret";
const string bucketName = "bucket";

var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
var request3 = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = keyName,
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60),
};
var url = await s3Client.GetPreSignedURLAsync(request3);//This works
var buckets = await s3Client.ListBucketsAsync();//This doesn't work
var objectListing = await s3Client.ListObjectsV2Async(new ListObjectsV2Request { BucketName = bucketName }); //This doesn't work either

I am getting "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records"

The error message is saying that your program does not have access to valid AWS credentials.
When creating a pre-signed URL, the operation is done locally (it just hashes some data) and does not actively 'use' any credentials. You will likely discover that the pre-signed URL it provides does not work since it was created with invalid credentials.
So... check your Access Key and Secret Key. A good way to do this is to try using them with the AWS CLI.
Also, it is generally more secure to store your AWS credentials in a configuration file rather than providing them in code. You can use the AWS CLI aws configure command to store credentials in a configuration file. If your code is running on an Amazon EC2 instance, then instead of providing credentials you should associate an IAM Role to the EC2 instance. This will automatically provide credentials to your program.

But if the pre-signed URL works, then what?

Obviously hard-coding credentials is never a good idea for production code.  It think it makes sense to show something on stack overflow.

The pre-signed URL might have worked because the object is public. Regardless, the error is saying the credentials are invalid. Where did you obtain those credentials? Does the Access Key start with AKIA? What happens if you use those credentials with the AWS CLI (eg aws s3 ls)?
